# Read data from firebase java-script

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Title

I want, to use variable like that, but I don't know how to make that.

```
console.log(`${db.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).get('prefix')}`)
```

Comment: We need more code than this.  Like, where is `message` defined?  Did you try: `console.log( db.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).get('prefix') )`?

Comment: @GAEfan message is defined, because its discord.js bot.
I used your code, and output is: Promise { <pending> }

Comment: uh...yeah... exactly - .get() returns a PROMISE that RESOLVES with a documentSnapshot - exactly as the documentation says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging an (ansyc) promise.  Try:

```
async function getPrefix() {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).get('prefix')
    return snapshot.val().prefix
}

console.log(await getPrefix())
```